# Android Recorded Video Compression

Tags: android, ffmpeg, compression, mediarecorder

This is a fairly long-winded issue and I've tried a couple of methods to fix it.

The ultimate problem is the user records a video and the video is to be uploaded via a REST API. The original solution was to use the camera app and pass the user though via an Intent. This method requires very little configuration for video optimisation - using the MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY and value of 0 gives MMS optimisation, which makes the videos pretty much unusable and I was hoping for something a little more around 480p.

So I started to create a custom video recorder using the `MediaRecorder` class. I managed to get this to work fine on a Nexus 4. I have 2 other test devices, a ZTE Blade and an Acer Iconica tab and it didn't work with either of these devices. 
The ZTE Blade complained about an incorrect video size but the video size I was using was given by `Camera.Parameters.getSupportedVideoSizes`. 
The Acer Iconica tab didn't have any valid `CamcorderProfile`'s. Calling `CamcorderProfile.hasProfile` on all of the available CamcorderProfile constants returned false. So if I was unsuccessful at loading a CamcorderProfile I attempted to configure MediaRecorder manually based on a device profile I found. This worked to an extent, but when I pressed record, I was presented with a black screen.

The second solution was to use the existing camera intent solution, but then compress the video using FFMPEG. My experience of using the Android NDK is nil, so it was a bit of a challenge. I managed to compile a library which interfaces natively with FFMEG - this one specifically (https://github.com/Batterii/android-ffmpeg-x264). The Videokit class initialises, but when it comes to calling `run` with the following arguments:

`videoKit.run(new String[] {"ffmpeg", "-i", file.getAbsolutePath(), "-vf",
                        "scale=-1:480", "-vcodec", "mp3g4", "-qscale", "3",
                        outputFile.getAbsolutePath()});`

The app suddenly stops with no exception and almost nothing in the logs except that the activity suddenly stopped.

The ultimate question I've been getting to is wether anyone has any solution to compress a video recorded on an Android device. If anyone can add to any of the issues I mentioned which hopefully will fix the issue, but I can't quite get working then I will appreciate that even more.

Thanks for reading and any help anyone has is incredibly appreciated.